# Getting exception on set default page programatically on feature activated in SharePoint-2010

Tags: event-receivers

my code on feature activated is

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
    {
        using (SPSite SiteInUserContext = new SPSite((properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb).Url))
        {
            using (SPWeb webInUserContext = SiteInUserContext.OpenWeb())
            {
                    webInUserContext.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPFolder objFolder = webInUserContext.RootFolder;
                    objFolder.WelcomePage = "default.aspx";
                    objFolder.Update();
                    webInUserContext.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }    
        }
    }
```

Exception details is:

[image]

**Note :** This exception occurs only when **set default page** on **feature activated** or **feature deactivated**.

How to resolve this exception ?

Thanks

Comment: Error you are seeing is general error and can come because of different reasons

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using,

```
objFolder.WelcomePage = "default.aspx";
```

try,

```
objFolder.WelcomePage = "Pages/default.aspx";
```

[Source](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/06/how-to-set-welcome-page-programmatically.html)

Comment: Still Getting exception..